# Extend two ES6 classes from one

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I intend to extend two ES6 classes from one, and two extended classes are used as controllers in Angular.

For Example,

```
class Base {
   constructor(name,age){
      this.name=name;
      this.age=age;
   }

   getDetails(){
      return this.name + ' ' + this.age; 
  }

}

class Controller1 extends Base{
   constructor(name,age){
     super(name,age); 
     this.getDetails = this.getDetails.bind(this);     
   }

   getDetails(){
      return super.getDetails();
  }

}


class Controller2 extends Base{
   constructor(name,age){
     super(name,age); 
     this.getDetails = this.getDetails.bind(this);     
   }

   getDetails(){
      return super.getDetails();
  }

}
```

in above example, controller1 and controller2 are registered as angular controllers. this works well, however what I have noticed, the Base class is called twice, each time each controller is accessed. Few questions:

is this design pattern correct? if yes, how to prevent base constructor to be invoked twice?
What I want to achieve is share few methods between both controllers. what would be ideal approach to achieve this, if above is not valid scenario?

Comment: The above code is incorrect, your missing a closing `}`, and neither controller1 or conroller2 are derived from Base, are we missing something?

Comment: oops, my bad. have corrected the typos.

Comment: I dont know about angular, but extending a base controller twice like you do here is totally fine.

Comment: You need Base to be constructed twice, how else would JavaScript deal with a Controler1 instance that has a different name & age than the Controler2 instance?

Comment: It works well, but the constructor of base class is called twice, it's not singleton. Any way to avoid that ?

Comment: You call `super` in each child constructor / method, this is the reason. No tricks here, you only get what you asked for.

Comment: ohk, thanks for clarifying